# how to show directory structure in javascript + HTML

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
let data = [
    {
        type: "folder",
        name: "animals",
        path: "/animals",
        children: [
            {
                type: "folder",
                name: "cat",
                path: "/animals/cat",
                children: [
                    {
                        type: "folder",
                        name: "images",
                        path: "/animals/cat/images",
                        children: [
                            {
                                type: "file",
                                name: "cat001.jpg",
                                path: "/animals/cat/images/cat001.jpg"
                            }, {
                                type: "file",
                                name: "cat001.jpg",
                                path: "/animals/cat/images/cat002.jpg"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, {
        type: "folder",
        name: "fruits",
        path: "/fruits",
        children: [{
            type: "file",
            name: "cat001.jpg",
            path: "/animals/cat/images/cat001.jpg"
        }]
    }
];
```

I have a json .I want to show a directory structure.using recursion I am able to get all items. I am trying to add `ul` and `li` to show my directory structure for visualization.

i want it looks like this

```
root
    |_ fruits
    |___ apple
    |______images
    |________ apple001.jpg
    |________ apple002.jpg
    |_ animals
    |___ cat
    |______images
    |________ cat001.jpg
    |________ cat002.jpg
```

it looks like this using `ul` and `li`

I tried like that

```
function printDir(data) {
        if(!data) return null
        data.map((i) => {
            console.log(i.name)
            if (i.children && i.children.length > 0) {
                printDir(i.children)
            }
        })
    }

    printDir(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the `printDir` method a parent list parameter. And then you create new lists and elements dynamically and add them to the parent list. Maybe like so...

```
function printDir(data, listElement) {
   if(!data) return null
   var list = document.createElement('ul')
   data.forEach((i) => {
      var item = document.createElement('li')
      item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i.name));
      list.appendChild(item)
      if (i.children && i.children.length > 0) {
         printDir(i.children, list)
      }
   })
   listElement.appendChild(list)
}
printDir(data, document.body)
```

Also note that while technically an array map would work, a forEach is more suitable here. Maps are for creating new arrays.